# Autocomplete Problems with Autofill Another Text Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I am trying to autofill input text 1 and fill a 2nd input based on the select on field 1. My sql works great.

In the html form - ids are formfieldname1 and formfieldname2

The autocomplete works on field 1, but wont carry the 2nd value over to the 2nd text field

At the bottom of my form field I have this

```
<script>
// JQUERY AUTOCOMPLETION


  $(function() {
    $( "#formfieldname1" ).autocomplete({
      source: "vessels6.php",
      minLength: 1, //search after one characters
    });
  });

  </script>
```

and on the vessels6.php page this...

```
<?php

// Basic oci_connect() database connection
   connection here

 $return_arr = array();

$term = strtoupper(trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$sql = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FROM TABLE1 WHERE MAX_DATE_CANCELED >= TRUNC(sysdate) and (FIELD1 LIKE '%$term%' OR FIELD2 LIKE '%$term%') ");

oci_execute($sql, OCI_DEFAULT);


while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sql, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {


    $row_array["label"] = $row['FIELD1'] . ' - ' . $row['FIELD2'];
    $row_array["value"] = $row['FIELD1'];

    $row_array['FIELD2'] = $row['FIELD2'];

array_push( $return_arr, $row_array );
}

oci_close($conn);

// Truncate, encode and return the results
$return_arr = array_slice($return_arr, 0, 8);
echo json_encode($return_arr),"\n";

?>
```

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete and I choose a selection in 1 text inout and want another input field to populate...

Comment: I only see one value, actually, that is the $term variable being used for both FIELD1 & FIELD2, also could you perhaps try to clarify the question a little bit, for instance a picture of the UI, what you'd expect and what you get for a result right now? - perhaps you might "rubber duck" your way out of this one :-)

Comment: By your statement "fill a 2nd input based on the select on field 1" do you mean fill that second input AS you type or after the select event?  And to clarify, are you using the jQuery UI Autocomplete? (it appears so but there are several available)